# How can I receive one OR two input?

Tags: c++

For example, I make a menu like this:

1. stack push
2. stack pop
3. stack print

Then, if I want to push `5` to the stack, I will type `1 5`.
But if I just want to pop or print the stack, I will just type `2` or `3`.

How can I handle those types? Now I can just receive `cin>>i` or `cin>>i>>n`, not both.

Comment: You just have to treat the various commands individually. After reading "1" you know there follows a number to push, so you read that. But after a "2" you know there's nothing more on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to process the individually.

```
int a;
std::cin >> a;
if(a == 1) //push
{
    int b;
    std::cin >> b;
    push(b);
}
else if(a == 2) { pop();}
else if(a == 3) { print(); }
else { std::cout << "invalid" << std::endl; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just write code to *decide* how much to read based on the situation!

If you know you will always only expect a number with the "stack push" command, only check for the extra number once you read the command.

It could look something like:

```
cin >> command;
if (command == 1) {
  int value;
  cin >> value;
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```